# Basis for $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ over $\Bbb Z[e_1,\dots,e_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory

I'm reading the introductory bits in Procesi's *Lie Groups*, and on p. 22 we have (paraphrasing)

> **Theorem 2.** $\mathcal{B}=\{x_1^{\large h_1}\cdots x_n^{\large h_n}: 0\le h_k\le n-k\}$ is a basis for the ring $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ considered over $\Bbb Z[e_1,\dots,e_n]$, where $e_i$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in the $x_i$.

I haven't been able to see why this is true. The previous theorem was the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, which was proven inductively with a recursive algorithm:

> If $x_n\mid f$ then $x_1\cdots x_n\mid f$, and dividing out we are left with a symmetric polynomial of smaller degree than before. Otherwise, write $f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},0)$ as a polynomial $p$ in the elementary symmetric polynomials $\hat{e}_i$ of the first $n-1$ variables, $p(\hat{e}_1,\dots,\hat{e}_{n-1})$. Now the polynomial $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)-p(e_1,\dots,e_{n-1})$$ is symmetric in all of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and evaluates to $0$ at $x_n=0$, i.e., is divisible by $x_n$. Induct.

Is there a straightforward adaptation of this with which we can argue for theorem 2? Or is there perhaps another way to see that it must be true? I feel I am missing something simple here.

Comment: Dear anon: You may look at Part 2 of Section G of Galois Theory: Lectures Delivered at the University of Notre Dame, by Emil Artin, freely and legally available [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197045).

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Cool, thanks.

Comment: Dear anon: In fact Artin proves the statement over $\mathbb Q$. Some extra work is needed to prove it over $\mathbb Z$. It is proved in Bourbaki (Alg. IV.6.5, Prop. 5). I wrote [a short text](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/%7Egaillapy/DIVERS/Selfcontained-proofs/) about this.

Comment: The above link will expire soon. Here is the [new link](http://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/Selfcontained-proofs/).

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I'm looking at the ([wayback-archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20201226125008/http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/Selfcontained-proofs/selfcontained-proofs-111213b.pdf)) of your self-contained proofs, and I cannot follow the proof of Theorem 3. At the end of that proof, you say that "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverse isomorphisms". Why is that the case? Wouldn't that argument show that any spanning set of a module is a basis?

Comment: @darijgrinberg - Thanks! I haven't thought about these kinds of things for a very long time, and I don't understand what I wrote, but I'm sure you're right and my text is incorrect. I'll try to fix it, but it might take a long time. I'll let you know.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - I don't think it's possible to salvage my text. Instead I tried to describe Bourbaki's proof (which I saw that you checked) in an answer in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261642/660.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thank you! I'll take a look at it tonight; it looks like it will make a good reference for my article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose I should actually come back to answer this. Main idea: for $1\le d<n$ we have

$$\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]^{S_d}=\bigoplus_{j=0}^d \Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]^{S_{d+1}}x_{d+1}^j. \tag{$\circ$}$$

They're both equal to $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]^{S_{d+1}}[x_{d+1}]$. Using $(\circ)$ we can begin unpeeling $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ by setting $d=1,2,\dots,n-1$. What I found interesting about this argument is that the outer layers of the onion are the *smaller* indices rather than the larger - initially I believed it'd be the reverse.

Comment: I don't understand what the notation $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]^{S_{d+1}}$ means. How does $S_{d+1}$ act on $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this fact in a paper I'm writing, so I've had to find references. Here are the ones I found:

- This fact is (DIFF.1.3) in [D. Laksov, A. Lascoux, P. Pragacz, and A. Thorup,
  *The LLPT Notes*, edited by A. Thorup, 1995--2018](http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/sympol.pdf). I have read that proof and can vouch for it.
- This fact is Chapter IV, § 6, no. 1, Theorem 1 c) of [Nicolas Bourbaki, *Algebra II: Chapters 4--7*, Springer 2003](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61698-3). Again, this is a proof I have read and can confirm.
- This fact is (5.1) in [I. G. Macdonald, *Notes on Schubert polynomials*, Montréal 1991](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eopecheni/macdonaldschubert.pdf).

Here are two further references that prove the analogue of this result for $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$:

- [Emil Artin, *Galois theory*, lectures delivered at the University of Notre Dame, edited and supplemented by Arthur N. Milgram, Notre Dame Mathematical Lectures **2**, University of Notre Dame Press, 2nd edition, 6th printing 1971](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/notre-dame-mathematical-lectures/Galois-Theory/toc/ndml/1175197041).
  In §II.G, Example 2 of this booklet, Artin proves that if $K$ is a field, then

  - the monomials $x_1^{h_1} x_2^{h_2} \cdots x_n^{h_n}$ with $h_i < i$ for each $i$ are linearly independent over the field of symmetric rational functions in
    $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ (and thus also linearly independent over the ring of symmetric polynomials), and
  - each polynomial in $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ can be represented as a polynomial in
    the $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and the symmetric polynomials such that its degree in $x_i$ is $< i$ (that is, as a linear combination of the monomials $x_1^{h_1} x_2^{h_2} \cdots x_n^{h_n}$ with $h_i < i$ over the ring of symmetric polynomials).

  Combining these two facts yields the claim in question when $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by a field $K$. I suspect it should be possible to derive the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ from that of a field, although this will unlikely give a particularly beautiful proof.
- [Adriano M. Garsia, *Pebbles and Expansions in the Polynomial Ring*, 21 July 2002](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Egarsia/somepapers/fnewpebbles.pdf) seems to prove this result in several ways. The explicit argument does use $\mathbb{Q}$, but I wouldn't be surprised if a proof for $\mathbb{Z}$ could be cobbled together from other things in this rather curious note.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of a theorem in Bourbaki's **Algebra II** mentioned by Darij Grinberg in [his answer above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4257715/660). Let me paste Darij's reference: Chapter IV, § 6, no. 1, Theorem 1 c) of [Nicolas Bourbaki, *Algebra II: Chapters 4--7*, Springer 2003](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61698-3). I like very much the proofs of Theorem (5.10) p. 16 and Proposition (1.3) p. 62 in Darij's first reference (namely [D. Laksov, A. Lascoux, P. Pragacz, and A. Thorup, *The LLPT Notes*, edited by A. Thorup, 1995--2018](http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/sympol.pdf)). I decided to post this answer just because Bourbaki's books are not freely available. I followed Bourbaki very closely, but I tried to give slightly more details. However I did not understand Bourbaki's proof of Statement (a), and hope the argument below is correct.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with one; let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be indeterminates; set
$$
E:=A[x_1,\ldots,x_n];
$$
let $s_0,\ldots,s_n$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials [[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)] in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$; let $t_0,\ldots,t_{n-1}$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials in $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$; let $G$ be the group formed by the $A$-automorphisms of $E$ which permute the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$; let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ formed by the $A$-automorphisms of $E$ which permute the $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$; consider the sub-$A$-algebras of invariants $E^G\subset E^H$; for $\alpha\in\mathbb N^n$ set $x^\alpha:=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$; let $\mathcal B$ be the subset of $E$ formed by the $x^\alpha$ with $\alpha_i<i$ for all $i$; and let $\mathcal C$ be the subset of $A[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$ formed by the $x^\alpha$ with $\alpha_i<i$ for all $i$.

**Theorem.** (a) The $A$-algebra $E^G$ is generated by $s_1,\ldots,s_n$, that is $E^G=A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]$.

(b) The elements $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ of $E$ are algebraically independent over $A$.

(c) The set $\mathcal B$ is a basis of the $E^G$-module $E$.

*Proof.* We argue by induction on $n$, the case $n=0$ being obvious. By induction hypothesis (applied to $A[x_n]$ instead of $A$) we have

(A) The $A[x_n]$-algebra $E^H$ is generated by $t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}$, that is $E^H=A[t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1},x_n]$.

(B) The elements $t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}$ of $E$ are algebraically independent over $A[x_n]$.

(C) The set $\mathcal C$ is a basis of the $E^H$-module $E$.

We clearly have

$(1)\qquad s_k=t_k+t_{k-1}x_n\qquad(1\le k\le n-1).$

We claim

$(2)\qquad t_k=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k\ (-1)^{k-i}\,s_i\,x_n^{k-i}$

for $1\le k\le n-1$. We prove $(2)$ by induction on $k$, the case $k=1$ being obvious. We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\ (-1)^{k-i}\,s_i\,x_n^{k-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\ (-1)^{k-i}\,s_i\,x_n^{k-i}+s_k=x_n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\ (-1)^{k-i}\,s_i\,x_n^{k-1-i}+s_k.
$$
By the induction hypothesis this is equal to $-x_n\,t_{k-1}+s_k$, and thus to $t_k$ by $(1)$. This proves $(2)$.

Now (A) and $(2)$ imply that the $A[x_n]$-algebra $E^H$ is generated by $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}$.

By (B) and (A), there is an endomorphism $u$ of the $A[x_n]$-algebra $E^H$ such that

$(4)\qquad u(t_k)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k\ (-1)^{k-i}\,t_i\,x_n^{k-i}\qquad(1\le k\le n-1),$

and $(1)$ yields $u(s_k)=u(t_k)+u(t_{k-1})\,x_n$, hence
$$
u(s_k)=u(t_k)+u(t_{k-1})\,x_n=\sum_{i=0}^k\ (-1)^{k-i}\,t_i\,x_n^{k-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\ (-1)^{k-1-i}\,t_i\,x_n^{k-i}=t_k,
$$
that is $u(s_k)=t_k$, and (B) implies that the elements $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}$ of $E$ are algebraically independent over $A[x_n]$. Hence the $A[x_n]$-algebra $E^H$ is generated by the algebraically independent elements $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}$, hence

(D) the elements $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1},x_n$ of $E$ are algebraically independent over $A$ and generate the $A$-algebra $E^H$, so that we have $E^H=A[s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1},x_n]$.

Let us prove (a). [As indicated above, I did not understand Bourbaki's proof of (a).] Let $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ be indeterminates. By (D) for each $f\in E^H$ there is a unique $f_*\in A[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ such that
$$
f=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f_*(s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1},x_n)
$$
and $f\mapsto f_*$ is an $A$-algebra isomorphism from $E^H$ onto $A[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ satisfying $(x_n)_*=y_n$. Denote the $y_n$-degree of $f_*$ by $d(f)$. Assume (a) is false and let $f\in E^G$ be a polynomial which is not in the sub-$A$-algebra $A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]$ of $E$ generated by $s_1,\ldots,s_n$. We can assume that $d(f)$ is minimum for these conditions. We clearly have $d(f)\ge1$. Write
$$
f_*=f_*(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{d(f)}f_{*,i}(y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1})\,y_n^i.
$$
Let $g\in E^H$ satisfy $g_*=f_{*,0}$, and thus
$$
g=f_{*,0}(s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1})\in A[s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}]\subset A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]\subset E^G.
$$
We see successively that $y_n$ divides $f_*-g_*$, that $x_n$ divides $f-g$ [because $(x_n)_*=y_n$], that $x_i$ divides $f-g$ for all $i$ [because $f-g$ is $G$-invariant], and that $s_n$ divides $f-g$. In particular $h:=(f-g)/s_n$ is a well defined element of $E^G$. We have
$$
f-g=s_n\,h=x_n\,t_{n-1}\,h=\left((-1)^{n-1}\,x_n^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ (-1)^{n-1-i}\,s_i\,x_n^{n-i}\right)h,
$$
the third equality following from $(2)$. This entails
$$
f_*-g_*=\left((-1)^{n-1}\,y_n^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ (-1)^{n-1-i}\,y_i\,y_n^{n-i}\right)h_*,
$$
and thus $d(h)=d(f)-n$. Since $h$ is in $E^G$ but not in $A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]$, we get a contradiction, and (a) is proved.

Let us prove (b). Let $z$ be an indeterminate. Replacing $z$ with $x_n$ in the well known and straightforward equality
$$
(z-x_1)\cdots(z-x_n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\ (-1)^{n-k}\,s_{n-k}\,z^k
$$
we get
$$
(-1)^{n+1}\,s_n=x_n^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\ (-1)^{n-k}\,s_{n-k}\,x_n^k.
$$
In view of Lemma 2 below (applied to $A[s_1, \ldots , s_{n-1}]$, $x_n$, $s_n$ and $n$ instead of $A$, $x$, $b$ and $\beta$), this implies that

(E) the set $\{1,x_n,\ldots,x_n^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the $A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]$-module $A[s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1},x_n]=E^H$ [see (D)]

and that $s_n$ is transcendental over $A[s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}]$. Since the elements $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}$ are algebraically independent over $A$ by (D), the proof of (b) is complete.

Finally let us prove (c). Denote the tower of $A$-algebras
$$
E^G=A[s_1,\ldots,s_n]\subset E^H=A[s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1},x_n]\subset E
$$
by $B\subset C\subset D$. By (E) the set $\{1,x_n,\ldots,x_n^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the $B$-module $C$ and by (C) the set $\mathcal C$ is a basis of the $C$-module $D$. This implies (c).

**Lemma 1.** Let $A$ be a commutative ring with one, let $x$ and $y$ be indeterminates, let $b\in A[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $\beta\ge1$ whose leading coefficient is invertible, and let $f$ be in $A[x]$. Then there is a unique representation of $f$ of the form

$(3)\qquad\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\beta-1}\ x^i\,g_i(b(x))$

with $g_i\in A[y]$.

*Proof*. Denoting by $a_{ij}$ the coefficient of $y^j$ in $g_i$ we can rewrite $(3)$ as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\beta-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\ a_{ij}\,x^i\,b(x)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\beta-1}a_{ij}\,x^i\right)b(x)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\ r_j(x)\,b(x)^j
$$
with $\deg r_j<\beta$. Thus it suffices to show the existence and uniqueness of a representation of $f$ of the form

$(4)\qquad\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\ r_j(x)\,b(x)^j$

with $\deg r_j<\beta$ for all $j$ and $r_j=0$ for $j$ large enough. We prove this by induction on $\deg f$, using the fact that, the leading coefficient of $b$ being invertible, $b$ is not a zero divisor and the division with remainder of any polynomial by $b$ is well defined.

Case $\deg f<0$, that is $f=0$: Assume by contradiction $0=\sum_{j=n}^\infty r_j(x)\,b(x)^j$ with $r_n\ne0$, and thus $0=\sum_{j=0}^\infty r_{j+n}(x)\,b(x)^j$, implying that $b$ divides $r_n$, which is impossible.

Case $\deg f\ge0$: Let $r_0$ be the remainder of $f$ divided by $b$. By induction hypothesis the polynomial $(f-r_0)/b$ has a unique representation of the form $(4)$, and the result follows quickly.

**Lemma 2.** Let $A$ be a commutative ring with one, let $x$ be an indeterminate, let $b\in A[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $\beta\ge1$ whose leading coefficient is invertible. Then, the set $\{1,x,\ldots,x^{\beta-1}\}$ is a basis of the $A[b]$-module $A[x]$, and the polynomial $b$ is transcendental over $A$.

*Proof*. This is merely Lemma 1, rewritten abstractly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you get $d(h) < d(f)$ in the proof of (a). But I can see the same argument being made with the usual total degree $\deg$ instead of $d$, so it's not a serious problem.

Comment: Nice writeup! I've made some other changes, which hopefully are not corrupting the spirit of the answer. (I find the last step to (E) slightly steep, as the $x_n$ is not literally a new indeterminate for the ring $A[s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1}]$ but merely an element transcendental over this ring. But I don't know how I would explain this any better.)

Comment: (I believe your proof of (a) is the same as Bourbaki's, although just as you, I'm not 100% sure of what Bourbaki's is. Fortunately, part (a) is the part with the easiest-to-find proofs in the literature.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg - Thank you very much for everything! I tried to fix the proof of (a).

Comment: I hope it's correct; I'm out of time. But I'd have argued using total degree, as it's much simpler (multiplication by $s_n = x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n$ clearly increases the total degree by $n$). Thanks once again for the useful writeup!