# What's the meaning of "condition for $a$, $b$, $c$ to be in geometrical progression"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, geometric-progressions

I'm reading Sawyer's *Prelude to Mathematics*, from page 34-35:

> [...]Prove that, if¹
>
> $$\frac{ac-b^2}{a-2b+c}=\frac{bd-c^2}{b-2c+c^2}$$
>
> Then the fractions just given are both equal to:
>
> $$\frac{ad-bc}{a-b-c+d}$$
>
> This question has a very definite form, and obviously to hammer it our
>   by a lengthy and sharpless calculation, while veryfing the result,
>   would bring one  no nearer to the heart of the question. What
>   interested me most was the question was the question, how did the
>   examiner come to think of this question?
>
> The pattern of the question includes the following aspects, $ac-b^2=0$
>   is the condition for the three quantities $a$, $b$, $c$ to be in
>   geometrical progression.
>
> 1 - It is assumed that $b$ and $c$ are unequal. The text does not discuss this point, as it's not relevant to the main theme. What suggested the question to the examiner.

I've [asked something similar before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189755/where-is-the-order-of-the-variables-inside-the-parentheses-coming-from) and [someone](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189766/25805) said me it's the [discriminant of the equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) but here I'm in doubt on what he meant with *conditon for* $a$, $b$, $c$ *to be in geometrical progression*.

Comment: The expression $ac-b^2$ is not a condition. The *equation* $ac-b^2=0$ is a condition for $a$, $b$, $c$ to be in GP.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, mistyped. I guess you kinda solved my problem. I didn't see the **damn** $=0$.

Comment: $0$ is easy to miss, it is so small.

Comment: It actually does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that $a,b,c$ are *in geometric progression* if there is some $r$ such that $b=ra$ and $c=r^2a$, so the sequence reads $a,ra,r^2a$.

Note that unless $a=b=c=0$, $r$ must be $b/a$ so the condition for $a,b,c$ to be in geometric progression is $c=(b/a)^2a=b^2/a$, or equivalently that $b^2-ac=0$.

Comment: I can't understand where's the $ r$ coming from.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I'm not sure what you mean. The existence of some such $r$ is the *definition* of being in geometric progression.

Comment: I was thinking that I could switch any of the $a$, $b$, $c$ and it would always equals zero. Then I thought that this would be a little dumb, I guess it's impossible for it to hold true for all numbers. Your answer has some kind of heuristic that is still unknown to me.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira You mean if $b^2-ac=0$ then $a^2-bc=0$? Certainly not, consider $a=1,b=2,c=4$.

Comment: I dunno how you proceed from the condition to the thing you made with the $r$. But it's starting to make sense.

Comment: Oh, you don't understand why $b^2-ac=0$ implies that there exists and $r$ such that $b=ra,c=r^2a$?

Comment: I'm still stuck in the *change the variables to numbers* thing, I guess I need to process information only in an algebrical way, when I see an algebrical expression.

Comment: Yep. I understand it, but shouldn't the complete solution be: "the condition for $b^2-ac=0$ to be in geometrical progression is possible only if $b=ra$ and $c=r^2a$"?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A sequence is in geometric progression, not an equation. So one would say "the condition for $a,b,c$ to be in geometric progression is that $b^2-ac=0$". The *definition* of $a,b,c$ being in geometric progression is that $b=ra$ and $c=r^2a$ for some $r$.

Comment: At [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/whats-the-meaning-of-condition-for-a-b-c-to-be-in-geometrical-progres#comment454757_198383): Yes, I have no idea why it implies the existence of a $r$ such that $b=ra,c=r^2a$.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira "I have no idea why it" When you say "it", you mean "$b^2-ac=0$"?

Comment: Yes. Just for curiosity, what else could it be?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I don't know what else it could be. But if $b^2-ac=0$ then we can let $r=b/a$ and we get $b=(b/a)a=ra$ and $c=(c/a)a=(ac/a^2)a=(b^2/a^2)a=r^2a$.